# Setup Azure b2c SSO with AWS

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We want to implement b2c SSO using custom policies on following scenario:

1. User logs into web app using b2c signin-singup policy (works fine).
2. After signin, web page displays links to call another web apps and when signed in user clicks on link, he/she should be able to access without signin using SSO.
3. One app is hosted on aws and others are hosted in azure.

Is there any github sample or documentation which walks through above scenario (Azure B2C SSO with AWS App)?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if understanding your question correctly. As long as your 2 apps recognized the JWT / SAML assertion issued by ADB2C policy, you should be able to achieve SSO by setting the URLs of your 2 apps in [Redirect URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application) to complete the sign in process.

Comment: I my second app running under aws using cognito for user authentication. I am not sure how I would setup aws app to trust azure b2c when its already using cognito. 

I was trying to find documentation but could not find anything to trust different domain and achieve SSO.

Comment: @Vikas did you get it working, I'm stuck on the same thing

Comment: @neerajmdas We have some business changes and this solution no longer needed. though you can refer details provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/272838/setup-b2c-sso-among-multiple-apps-options.html